# Back variables from InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

im using cordova 2.5.0 and I have problems to communicate a new window with my app with the InAppBrowser. It is possible to send back information from a page opened with InAppBrowser plugin to my cordova app.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a little involved (like [polling](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser) or [custom urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme)), but since inAppBrowser [3.0.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#300-apr-12-2018) you can use `AllowedSchemes` with the `customscheme` event. This is not documented yet, but can be used as follows.

To your `config.xml`, add

```xml
<preference name="AllowedSchemes" value="myscheme" />
```

with the following code in your Cordova app:

```js
function onCustomScheme(e) {
  if (e.url.match(/^myscheme:\/\/message\b/)) {
     var q = parseQueryString(e.url);
     console.log("Got foo message: " + q.text);
  }
}

url = "https://my.example.com/";
app = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank");
app.addEventListener("customscheme", onCustomScheme, false);
```

Then from the website opened in the inAppBrowser, you can embed a link like this, which shows the message *hi there* in the console if you follow it.

```
<a href="myscheme://message?text=hi+there">Test</a>
```

This won't work with Cordova 2.5 (it looks like you'll need at least 3.1), but as 8 is out now, it's probably a good idea to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Since then other ways were introduced as well, like the `beforeload` event ([PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/276)) and `postMessage` ([PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/362)).